# Function with optional arg and omitted named params cannot recieve model instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I just ran into some very confusing behavior in Rails.

(Ruby v2.3.1p112, Rails v4.2.4)

### Summary

If I call a method that accepts an optional param as well as named params, and only give it an instance of a model, that model instance gets converted into a Hash.  Why?

Specifically: `def test(a=nil, b:nil)` called with `test(merchant_instance)` receives a `Hash`, not a `Merchant`.

Any other method signature or call does not reproduce this behavior.

### Examples

Given the following three methods:

```
def test_one(a=nil)
  # This one always works
  raise ArgumentError, "Received a #{a.class}"
end

def test_two(a=nil, b:nil)
  # This one only works when I also specify `b`
  raise ArgumentError, "Received a #{a.class}"
end

def test_three(a, b:nil)
  # This one also always works
  raise ArgumentError, "Received a #{a.class}"
end
```

These calls receive a `Merchant` instance, as expected:

- `test_one( Merchant.find(42) )`
- `test_two( Merchant.find(42), b:nil )`
- `test_three( Merchant.find(42), b:nil )`
- `test_three( Merchant.find(42) )`

This is the only call that instead receives a `Hash`:

- `test_two( Merchant.find(42) )`

---

After further testing, these method signatures also receive the `Merchant` instance when only given that single arg:

- `def test(a:nil, b:nil)`
- `def test(a=nil, b=nil)`

Meaning this Hash-conversion only happens when the method signature contains an optional arg AND optional named args, and only when the named args are not specified when called.

---

**Why is this happening?**

**Is this a bug within ActiveRecord?**

Comment: Which version of Ruby? Which version of Rails?

Comment: Apologies for not including version info!  I've edited the question

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't reproduce this with Rails5.2 and Ruby2.5.1 so maybe try upgrading. Does ActiveRecord in 4.2.4 include `#to_hash` or `#to_h` methods on models? Is your `test_two` calling them while building the argument list?

Comment: @muistooshort: Thanks for the lead. One of the helpers included in the Merchant model defined a #to_hash method, which was being called only when the method signature included a mixture of optional and optional named args.  Removing this method stopped the erroneous behavior.  I'll have to go through the application to see where this is being used and if it's safe to remove/rename.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a bug in ActiveRecord, more likely a bug in the ruby you're using.

Is it actually converting the ActiveRecord object to a Hash, or is it converting your parameter list to a hash? Because in ruby, if you aren't using keyword arguments, you can still call like this:

```
def my_method(obj=nil)
  puts obj.inspect
end

my_method(a: nil, b: nil)
```

Should print `{:a=>nil, :b=>nil}`.

This implicit hash parameters behavior was the precursor to keyword parameters.

Comment: It is absolutely converting the ActiveRecord object into a Hash, but *only* in the very specific scenario I outlined.  The hash received contains all of the data on the object.